# MS SQL Server insert speed using SqlCommand

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables where I have to add a lot of rows sometimes. Last case was 800000 rows into table1, and 3 times more into table 2.

I use following stored procedure to insert rows, because I don't see way to use bulk copy, considering tables have auto id fields and have a foreign key relation.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddOrderBookEntry 
 @Moment datetime,
 @LocalTime datetime,
 @BB decimal(18,4),
 @BO decimal(18,4),
 @QBB float,
 @QBO float,
 @SumTr float = NULL,
 @QSumTr float = NULL,
 @IV float = NULL,
 @InstrumentId bigint,
 @AverageValues Averages READONLY
AS
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO dbo.OrderBook
 VALUES (@Moment,@LocalTime,@BB,@BO,@QBB,@QBO,@SumTr,@QSumTr,@IV,@InstrumentId)

 DECLARE @OBID bigint
 SELECT @OBID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

 INSERT INTO dbo.OrderbookAverages
 select N, BN, [ON], @OBID from @AverageValues

END
GO
```

It works, but what bothers me is speed. According to my measures, it takes app 1.75 milliseconds for a record to be added. I am measuring speed from .net application that writes data into db. This application is on the same computer as SQL Server.

So question is - is this speed okeyish for the approach I use? Or it can be improved?

Comment: What I see in your example you are executing the proc for each record, but you will gain a better performance if you invest in you infrastructure reorganisation.
INSERT from a SELECT will work time faster rather than individual inserts

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean a userdefined type for OrderBookEntry that will allow to pass a set of entries as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 20 minutes for 800.000 records isn't very fast, but only you can decide if it is fast enough.

You could get away with using bulk insert by using a two-step process. First load the data into the two tables using bulk insert and then joining them by somehow looking up the auto id from the first table. Maybe by assigning the matching rows an id that you generate beforehand (a guid might work).

This would probably be much faster, but you must consider if it is worth spending time on. 
How often do you run these imports for instance? If you do them five times a day then any speedup will be worth it. If you do them once every month then probably not :-)

Comment: Most of the time this application works with rather thin dataflow, but sometimes analysts want to upload previous days data, and then its not cool. But I was mostly thinking that there could be something I am missing (I had a rather long break since last time db programming), like e.g. "Oh use entity framework, its 1000 times faster then that"

Comment: And we are rather tight on disk space, and guid would be larger then bigint, right?

Comment: No, EF won't magically make it faster.  This suggestion is a good one, do the bulk insert to the parent, bulk insert the children into a temp table then join those to the parent to get the FK right.

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem! If you need to speed up the process then I think you must either use bulk copy or do all processing on the sql server. You might get a nice speedup by running everything inside sql server, possibly using managed code stored procedures.

Comment: EF will not help, it will probably make everything slower! A guid is larger than a bigint (16 bytes vs 8 bytes for a bigint), but even for 800000 records the difference is only 6 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Often there is a need to send a very large number of rows from business code to the database. There are a number of ways to do it:

Call insert statements a row at a time for the entire data
Serialize the data into some flat format (CSV or XML), send it to a stored procedure as a large string, unserialize the string in the stored procedure TSQL and do an insert.
Save the data into a flat file format on the database server. Run a DTS package or like to read up the file.
SqlBulkCopy!

Every since I discovered SqlBulkCopy, I’ve loved it. MS SQL Server includes a popular command called bcp for moving data from one table to another on one server or between servers. The SqlBulkCopy is a class that provides similar functionality.

SqlBulkCopy is way faster than multiple insert statements, serializing/ deserializing the data, or saving the data out to a file system and running an import.  Its also has no limit on the data you can send across and very efficient in the way it handles inserts.

This is how simple it is to use it. In the example we have a function that writes copies are DataTable into a MS SQL database table called “tblFooBar”.

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
…

Function WriteToDB(DataTable dt)

{

    SqlBulkCopy sqlBC = new SqlBulkCopy(dbconnectionstring);

    sqlBC.BatchSize = 25000;

    sqlBC.BulkCopyTimeout = 60;

    sqlBC.DestinationTableName = “dbo.tblFooBar” ;

    sqlBC.WriteToServer(dt);

}
…
```

The MSDN link is:

[Link for the details of bulk insert](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: I thought about bulk insert, but than I will have to find ids of inserted rows. Considering there could be a number of writer applications, that would be messy imho.